# F# How to Count Number of elements in a list that match some criteria?

Tags: f#

I am prototyping how I am going to handle Double.NaN values in an F# array, and the first step, trying to simply count how many there are, has me stumped.  The value "howMany" comes back as zero in my code, but I know there are 2, because I set 2 value to be Double.NaN.  Can anyone point out what I am missing?  Thanks!

```
let rnd = new System.Random()
let fakeAlphas = Array.init 10  (fun _ -> rnd.NextDouble());;

fakeAlphas.[0] <- Double.NaN;
fakeAlphas.[1] <- Double.NaN;

let countNA arr = arr |> Array.filter (fun x -> x = Double.NaN) |> Array.length;;

let howMany = countNA fakeAlphas;;
```

Answer (score 14):

To answer the general question in the title:

```
let HowManySatisfy pred = Seq.filter pred >> Seq.length
```

for example

```
let nums = [1;2;3;4;5]
let countEvens = nums |> HowManySatisfy (fun n -> n%2=0) 
printfn "%d" countEvens
```

Answer (score 10):

`Double.NaN = n` is false for all n. See [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx) for Double.NaN.

Instead use `Double.IsNaN`. See [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to use the Double.IsNan method. So your filter function would be:

```
(fun x -> Double.IsNan x)
```

I believe the issue is that NaN never equals anything -- even another NaN!

Comment: Yup, _"Use IsNaN to determine whether a value is not a number. It is not possible to determine whether a value is not a number by comparing it to another value equal to NaN."_ ~http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(VS.100).aspx

Comment: How about `Double.IsNan` instead of `(fun x -> Double.IsNan x)`?

Comment: @Cogwheel: you're correct. The anonymous function is unnecessary.